# Is it possible to patch a non-dev version of a module?

Tags: 7, version-control

I can create patches from dev copies of modules just fine thanks to this [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1054616), but when I try to create a patch from a non-dev version I get troubles. If possible, How do I do this?

Comment: you are creating a patch? or applying a patch?

Comment: Creating. I think I may have solved it, though.

Comment: nope didn't work. I do want to apply it after creating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a few differences from the process described on that documentation page.

1. In Step 1, when creating the topic branch, specify the commit from
   which to create the branch. You can do this by appending a commit
   ID, a tag name, or an existing branch name to your `git branch`
   command. Tag name should work, because Drupal project releases are
   tagged with the project version number. So if you wanted to patch
   off of the 7.x-1.5 version of a module, instead of this:

   > git branch [issue-number]-[short-description]

   You would do this:

   > git branch [issue-number]-[short-description] 7.x-1.5
2. You would skip Step 4 and 5, since those steps are for making apply
   to the most recent dev version.
3. In Step 6, when using the `git diff` command to create your patch
   file, you now want to diff against the commit that represents the
   unmodified version. Again, we can use the tag/version name.

   > git diff 7.x-1.5 > [project_name]-[short-description]-[issue-number]-[comment-number].patch